# Why does Rukia fall for so long when getting thrown by Yammy?

Tags: bleach

So Rukia gets grabbed by Yammy in Las Noches:

[image]

Yammy then throws her at the ground, but she is falling for more than a couple of minutes:

[image]

But Ichigo jumps from above the sky in Las Noches and makes it to her before she hits the ground:

[image]

I know physics is not always followed in anime but this just seems *so far off*. Why would the animators do this? The scene does not seem way too important to me, and you don't even see Ichigo save Rukia—it is implied that he does as he is seen standing next to her when the smoke clears.

This happens at the end of episode 285 and into episode 286.

Comment: Like I said, this is *way* beyond dramatic.

Comment: could you please add the episode number and approximate timing?

Comment: @user1306322 added

Answer (score 3):

I timed it at [5:18-5:34ish](http://www.anime-realm.com/Bleach-episode-286-2-sub.html) for the animation of release to smoke cloud.

Anyways, the stretch of physics would be bad if he threw her *underneath* him, near his feet. But my eyes saw his arm stretched out away from his body after the toss in an attempt to basically spear-chuck her.

My speculation would be that they're relying on a set of three overlapping times: Ichigo's catchup (shortest span of observed time), Yammy's toss (short span of observed time), and Rukia's trajectory (longest span of observed time to get in frantic dialogue).

For anime fluff, this feels around average.